# Get specific value from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays

I'm parsing an XML and saving result to NSMutableArray. When I do NSLog,

```
NSLog(@"Data : %@",_data);
```

I'm getting

```
Data : (
        {
        SessionToken = 9e72dd029e0e8268380b919356881935;
    }
)
```

I only want 9e72dd029e0e8268380b919356881935 from the array. What is the best solution to achieve this?

EDIT : There will be only one SessionToken at a time.

Comment: Your data is an array of dictionary. You just need to use "SessionToken" key and you will get the value.

Comment: Will there be only one sessionToken at all times?

Comment: An NSDictionary can only map one object to one instance of a key.

Comment: @Anupdas no, sessionToken differs all the time.

Comment: @jack My question was if _data array contain more than one sessionToken at a time?

Comment: @Anupdas no, only one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there will be only one session at a time.

```
NSDictionary *session = [_data lastObject];
NSString *sessionToken = session[@"SessionToken"];
```

OR with literals

```
NSString *sessionToken = _data[0][@"SessionToken"];
```

Comment: @Viral As per the OP, there will be only one object in the array. If I don't use literals i always use lastObject as it will not crash if there are no objects. The second alternative was to show how this can be done with literals thats it.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this code :

```
for (NSDictionary *data1 in _data) {
    NSlog("session token %@",[data1 objectForKey:@"SessionToken"]);//Other wise add into another array which contain session token.. only..
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this, expected ']'

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([_data count]) {
    NSDictionary *dic = [_data objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Data : %@",[dic objectForKey:@"SessionToken"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (NSDictionary *data1 in _data) {
    NSlog("session token %@",[data1 valueForKey:@"SessionToken"]);
}
```

Comment: You could potentially expand this answer / explain it a bit more.

Comment: @Rogue it returns the value associated with a given key.if your json value is array with in array use like this         [[data1 valueForKey:@"SessionToken"]objectAtIndex:0]